# urban airship trouble for iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

My app is for both iOS 7 and iOS 8. Because of this setup, urban airship is now working. All I do is grab the `Airship` directory and put it in my project. Then before I do anything else, I try running my project. Already I am getting errors like

```
ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/AirshipKit.framework/AirshipKit) for architecture arm64
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

How exactly do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

AirshipKit.framework is only meant for iOS 8+ only as documented here: http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/push/ios.html#download-install-our-library-frameworks . If you are still supporting iOS 7 then do not link against the framework and link against the static library instead: libUAirship-.a